# Parametrizing raw type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I use Eclipse IDe and Apache Commons DBUtils library and I have some own row processor classes extended from [BasicRowProcessor class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/BasicRowProcessor.html). In this classes I am overriding these two DButils' methods:

```
public <T> T toBean(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

and

```
public <T> List<T> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

My implementation of `toBeanList` method is as follows:

```
   @Override
    public LinkedList<Object> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class clazz) {
        try {
            LinkedList<Object> newlist = new LinkedList<Object>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                newlist.add(toBean(rs, clazz));
            }
            return newlist;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

I loop through a `ResultSet` and call `toBean` method for its all records. It works, but Eclipse reports some problem (probably related to Java generic), please see this screenshot:

[image]

When I set parametrize `clazz` argument as `Class<TaskItem> clazz` Eclipse reports another problem and it doesn't override method in upper class `BasicRowProcessor`.

[image]

How can I solve this issue? What am I doing wrong? Or is it safe to ignore this warning? Probably it will be very easy to solve this, but I haven't found a solution.

**Edit:**

I tried to parametrize my two methods but Eclipse reports that I need to override super type.

`toBeanList` method:

```
@Override
    public LinkedList<TaskItem> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<TaskItem> clazz) {
        try {
            LinkedList<TaskItem> newlist = new LinkedList<TaskItem>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                newlist.add(toBean(rs, clazz));
            }
            return newlist;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

And `toBean` method:

```
@Override
    public TaskItem toBean(ResultSet rs, Class<TaskItem> clazz) throws SQLException {

        TaskItem item = new TaskItem();
     // some stuff....       
        return item;

    }
```

And this Eclipse reports:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
public <T> List<T> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

The placeholder for the type is `T`. This means the the result list is a list of `T` and the Class that is passed as a parameter is a `Class<T>`. Therefore when you want a `LinkedList<Object>` you need to pass a `Class<Object>` to the method.

When you want to pass a `Class<TaskItem>` you will get a `LinkedList<TaskItem>`. Therefore it will be

```
public List<TaskItem> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<TaskItem> type) throws SQLException
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it but when I declare return type to List<TaskItem> and Class<TaskItem> Eclipse reports that I need to override a supertype method. That is a problem what I'm trying to solve. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you are using when you parameterise the method call? i.e. the images from above without the warnings.

Comment: thanks, I added an example of my methods to my original question.

Comment: try adding the `throws SQLException` to your methods

Comment: It doesn't help, the same problem occurs. Isn't better to ignore this warning? I cam compile my project but only Eclipse reports this warning.

Comment: It should work (otherwise you couldn't compile your projects). Try to clean your project and/or restart your eclipse/computer. Sometimes that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your method this way:

```
public LinkedList<Object> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<Object> clazz)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `T` in that declaration is a type variable, and it has to be consistent across wherever you're using it. In this case, all of the `T`s on the method (and elsewhere in the class, such as on `toBean`) have to match. The point of having the class variable is to tell Java what type of object you're extracting from the `ResultSet`, so you would need to declare your method like this:

```
public LinkedList<TaskItem> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<TaskItem> class)
```

Note that in this case, if you already know that you're using the `TaskItem` specifically, passing it to `toBeanList` wouldn't be necessary except that the method you're overriding requires it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the method definition:

```
public <T> List<T> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

The 'T' of Class should be same as the T of the List.

So your method definition should be:

```
public List<TaskItem> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<TaskItem> type) throws SQLException{
//Code
}
```

Is this how your method looks?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**toBeanList** method

```
@Override
public <T> List<T> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(toBean(rs, type));
    }
    return list;
}
```

**toBean** method

```
@Override
public <T> T toBean(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException {
    TaskItem item = new TaskItem();

    //populate item ...

    return type.cast(item);
}
```